# html-minifier fails with "ERROR: The specified config file doesn’t exist or is unreadable"

Tags: npm, bundling-and-minification

I'm using the npm package "[html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier)" (v1.0.0) and am trying to run the command (from Linux Mint, on the command line):

```
html-minifier -c html-minifier.cfg -o lib/welcome.html client/welcome.html
```

However it fails with the error:

```
ERROR: The specified config file doesn’t exist or is unreadable:
/var/www/projectfolder/html-minifier.cfg
```

Despite the existence and readability of that file.

Why might that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I installed v0.8.0:

```
sudo npm install -g html-minifier@0.8.0
```

and then the command given in the question worked. Looks like it's a bug specific to v1.0.0. I've logged an issue against the project to get it resolved.